# × TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'form')

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios, react-hooks

I am trying to trigger the handleSubmit function for the form but getting the error mentioned in the title. Adding the code for the handle submit function as well as the form below. Please help out

I am using a react template from CoreUI for this so most tags are from that. The form will be nested under the CCard Tag and the submit button is in the Card footer. I have the form in a separate component and i am storing the values in the state which are to be passed to the post api call on submit which is inside the handle submit function

```
const DataSources = () => {
  const [collapsed, setCollapsed] = React.useState(true)
  const [showElements, setShowElements] = React.useState(true)
  const entryList = []
  const [tableEntries, setTableEntries] = React.useState(entryList)

  function handleSubmit(){
      // POST request using axios with set headers
      const article = { "connectionType":"InstagramConnection","id":"e5ee8320-a307-448b-a0ed-0829a187050f","name":this.state.value,"accessCredentials":{"id":2,"token":this.state.access_token} };
      const headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
      };
      Axios.post('http://localhost:8080/api/connections', article, { headers })
          .then(response => console.log(response.data.id));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get('http://localhost:8080/api/connections')
     .then(res => {
      console.log(res.data);
      const newList = entryList.concat(res.data);
      Array.prototype.forEach.call(res.data, response => {
        setTableEntries(prevTableEntries => [...prevTableEntries,response]);
      });

      console.log(tableEntries);
     })
     .catch(err => console.log(err));
   }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <CRow>
        <CCol xs="12" md="10">
          <p className="h1">Data Sources</p>
        </CCol>
        <CCol xs="12" md="2">
          <CDropdown className="m-1" size="lg" align="center" size="lg"> 
              <CDropdownToggle color="secondary">
                Select Client
              </CDropdownToggle>
              <CDropdownMenu>
                  <CDropdownItem>Client 1</CDropdownItem>
                  <CDropdownItem>Client 2</CDropdownItem>
                </CDropdownMenu>
          </CDropdown>
        </CCol>       
      </CRow>
      <br></br>
      <CRow>
        <CCol xs="12" md="4">
          <CCard>
            <CCardHeader>
              Add Data Source
            </CCardHeader>
            <CCardBody>
              <CForm ref={ (ref) => { this.form = ref; } } className="form-horizontal" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <CFormGroup>
                  <Facebook />
                </CFormGroup>
              </CForm>
            </CCardBody>
            <CCardFooter>
              <CButton type="submit" size="sm" color="primary" value="Submit" onClick={ () => { this.form.dispatchEvent(new Event('submit')) } }><CIcon name="cil-scrubber" /> Add Connection</CButton>
              <CButton type="reset" size="sm" color="danger"><CIcon name="cil-ban" /> Reset</CButton>
            </CCardFooter>
          </CCard>
        </CCol>
        <CCol xs="12" md="8">
          <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">#</th>
                <th scope="col">Id</th>
                <th scope="col">App Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Connection Type</th>
                <th scope="col">Options</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>          
                {tableEntries.map((item) => (
                  <>
                  <tr>
                  <th scope="row">1</th>
                  <td>{item.id}</td>
                  <td>{item.name}</td>
                  <td>{item.connectionType}</td>
                  <td>
                    <CDropdown className="m-1" size="lg">
                      <CDropdownToggle color="secondary">
                        Select Option
                      </CDropdownToggle>
                      <CDropdownMenu>
                        <CDropdownItem>Delete</CDropdownItem>
                        <CDropdownItem>Reauthorize</CDropdownItem>
                      </CDropdownMenu>
                    </CDropdown>
                  </td>
                  </tr>
                  </>
                ))}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </CCol>
      </CRow>
      
      
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: What is `ref={ (ref) => { this.form = ref; } }` supposed to do? Also, you're using functional components but also `this.state`? The latter is used in class components.

Comment: I am very much new to this. I am trying to run the handleSubmit function on form submit and in one of the online examples i saw it was basically using this ref attribute to reference to another function which would then trigger the submit event that would be used by handleSubmit function. If there are better ways to do this please guide me on the same

Comment: Where are the CC elements coming from? Can you link me to the library?

Comment: https://coreui.io/react/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/ - here is the documentation for the template

Comment: Tried to create a controlled input but failed. Not sure what the deal is with that library (I don't like it) but you can just use code like this to handle the form: https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-glitter-gqf99?file=/src/App.js